# Create tabular/table with exact width

Tags: tables, spacing

## The Problem

I want to create a table with an exact width. So I thought I'd use the
`tabular*` environment. Then I realised, that it might be a little
more difficult than I imagined in the beginning. The problem is the
horizotal alignment/positioning: `\tabcolsep` and `\arrayrulewidth`
change the positioning.

### No additional packages loaded

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=3.5cm,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.6pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\textbf{No packages}\par\vspace{5pt}
\begin{tabular*}{14mm}{ |@{} p{7mm} @{}|@{} p{7mm} @{}| } % 1: shifts---because of the vlines
    \hline
    \hspace{2pt}foo & \hspace{2pt}bar
\end{tabular*} (1)
\par\vspace{5pt}


\verb|\tabcolsep=0pt|\par
\begin{tabular*}{14mm}{ | p{7mm} | p{7mm} | } % 2: default, alignment is correct
    \hline
    \hspace{2pt}foo & \hspace{2pt}bar
\end{tabular*} (2) default

\begin{tabular*}{14mm}{% 3: manually corrected outer vertical line
        @{\kern.5\arrayrulewidth}|@{\kern-\arrayrulewidth}%
        p{7mm} | p{7mm}%
        @{\kern-.5\arrayrulewidth}| }
    \hline
    \hspace{2pt}foo & \hspace{2pt}bar
\end{tabular*} (3) fixed1
\par\vspace{5pt}


\verb|\tabcolsep=2pt|\par
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{tabular*}{14mm}{ | p{7mm} | p{7mm} | } % 4: default, alignment is NOT correct
    \hline
    foo & bar
\end{tabular*} (4) default

\begin{tabular*}{14mm}{% 5: manually corrected with tabcolsep active
        @{\kern.5\arrayrulewidth}|%
        p{\dimexpr 7mm-2\tabcolsep-.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}%
        |%
        p{\dimexpr 7mm-2\tabcolsep-.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}%
        |}
    \hline
    foo & bar
\end{tabular*} (5) fixed2

\begin{tabular*}{14mm}{% 6: manually corrected(2) with tabcolsep active
        p{\dimexpr 7mm-2\tabcolsep-0 \arrayrulewidth\relax}%
        p{\dimexpr 7mm-2\tabcolsep-.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}%
        |}
    \hline
    foo & bar
\end{tabular*} (6) fixed3
\end{document}
```

[image: result1]

First impression: the left vline is not aligned with the
table border. As one can see, I first tried to get rid of all
`\tabcolsep`s manually (1). This still has the widths of the vlines
though. Curiously, the default behaviour with `\tabcolsep=0pt` does
manage shifts caused by the vlines (2). One can fix the ugly outer
vlines (not matching the edge of the table) manually (3). But this
still leaves the problem of horizontal spacing in the cells. One could
put a shifted parbox in there. A lot of work for many cells. So it
might be better to use `\tabcolsep`. If I do, the default behaviour
is shown in (4). Not working correctly, so one has to start fixing
again. Curiously, this time one has to consider the width of the
vlines in the fix (5). Obviously this is the better solution compared
to (3). But this leads to potentially many manual adjustments with
big tables, especially if there are not vlines between every column,
as this has to be considered (6).

### With package `array`

Trying to use one of the packages that should improve the behaviour
of tables, I tried the `array` package:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=3.5cm,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.6pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\textbf{array package}\par\vspace{5pt}
\begin{tabular*}{14mm}{ |@{} p{7mm} @{}|@{} p{7mm} @{}| } % 1: shifts---because of the vlines
    \hline
    \hspace{2pt}foo & \hspace{2pt}bar
\end{tabular*} (1)
\par\vspace{5pt}


\verb|\tabcolsep=0pt|\par
\begin{tabular*}{14mm}{ | p{7mm} | p{7mm} | } % 2: default, alignment is correct
    \hline
    \hspace{2pt}foo & \hspace{2pt}bar
\end{tabular*} (2) default

\begin{tabular*}{14mm}{% 3: manually corrected outer vertical line
        |@{\kern-\arrayrulewidth}%
        p{7mm}%
        @{\kern-.5\arrayrulewidth}|@{\kern-.5\arrayrulewidth}%
        p{7mm}%
        @{\kern-\arrayrulewidth}| }
    \hline
    \hspace{2pt}foo & \hspace{2pt}bar
\end{tabular*} (3) fixed1
\par\vspace{5pt}


\verb|\tabcolsep=2pt|\par
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{tabular*}{14mm}{ | p{7mm} | p{7mm} | } % 4: default, alignment is NOT correct
    \hline
    foo & bar
\end{tabular*} (4) default

\begin{tabular*}{14mm}{% 5: manually corrected with tabcolsep active
        |%
        p{\dimexpr 7mm-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}%
        |%
        p{\dimexpr 7mm-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}%
        |}
    \hline
    foo & bar
\end{tabular*} (5) fixed2

\begin{tabular*}{14mm}{% 6: manually corrected(2) with tabcolsep active
        p{\dimexpr 7mm-2\tabcolsep-0\arrayrulewidth\relax}%
        p{\dimexpr 7mm-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth\relax}%
        |}
    \hline
    foo & bar
\end{tabular*} (6) fixed3
\end{document}
```

[image: result2]

The left alignment of the vline seems to be corrected automatically,
good. Sadly, this isn't really improving the overall result:
To the right, the same issues appear. (1) is the same as before
with corrected left vline. (2) shows the default behaviour with
`\tabcolsep=0pt`. Again, manual fixing is needed (3). Better
is to use `\tabcolsep` though. The default behaviour is shown in
(4). This obviously has to be fixed as well (5). Here the situation
is even worse than without the `arrays` package. One has to consider
whether the column is an outer column or not, in order to fix the
parbox widths. This doesn't get better if some vlines are not used
(6). `tabularx` result looks similar. There is always the need to
adjust manually.

### tabularx package

```
\documentclass[varwidth=3.5cm,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{document}
\textbf{tabularx package}\par\vspace{5pt}

\begin{tabular*}{14mm}{% 1: target layout
        |%
        p{\dimexpr 7mm-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}%
        |%
        p{\dimexpr 7mm-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}%
        |}
    \hline
    foo & bar
\end{tabular*} (1) target

\begin{tabularx}{14mm}{ |X|X| }% default without manual sizing
    \hline
    foo & bar
\end{tabularx} (2) default1

\begin{tabularx}{14mm}{ |>{\hsize=7mm}X|X| }
    \hline
    foo & bar
\end{tabularx} (3) default2

\begin{tabularx}{14mm}{ |>{\hsize=\dimexpr7mm-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|X| }
\hline
foo & bar
\end{tabularx} (4) fixed
\end{document}
```

[image: result3]

This does some things better (e.g. right vline is always aligned),
but one still has to do manual calculations based on vlines before
or after...

## Correct tables by default?

I would like to use a normal environment without the need to adjust
it manually. Something like

```
\newlength{\mylength}
\def\mylength{-2\tabcolsep-.5\arrayrulewidth}
```

could work, if I can make them sensitive to the context vlines. Using
`array`,

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}
```

could work almost automated, if it could see surrounding vlines. I
don't want to create a ton of column types and take care of which
one to take (outer, inner column, surrounded by zero, one, two vlines).

**How can I get a table of the predefined width without manual
interaction**?

Comment: Did you try `tabularx` (which, incidentally, loads `array`)?

Comment: Yep, exactly the same as `array` for my tests.

Comment: If you do in the very first example `\begin{tabular*}{14mm}{|@{}p{7mm}@{\hspace*{-2\arrayrulewidth}}|@{}p{7mm}@{\hspace*{-\arrayrulewidth}}|}` then the gaps disappear. Same for `\begin{tabular*}{\dimexpr14mm+3\arrayrulewidth}{|@{}p{7mm}@{}|@{}p{7mm}@{}|}`, in which case the width between the vlines is 7mm each.

Comment: I have an error of 0.01mm, maybe due to the thickness pdf viewer measurement ruler.

Comment: @marmot this is working, but still manual adjustment is needed depending on the used vlines, similar to my tries above.

Comment: it isn't clear why you are doing `\begin{tabularx}{14mm}{ |>{\hsize=7mm}X|X| }`  changing hsize like that is explictly documented as breaking `tabularx` in the `tabularx` manual. If you want one fixed width column and one X use `p{7cm}|X`

Comment: if you specify a total width with `tabular*` then you must use `\extracolsep` to add the stretchable space to allow that width to be achieved.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you're right, relative calculation has to be sufficient with the `tabularx` package then. I don't see how `\extracolsep` is helping me.

Comment: @nox `\extracolsep` is _required_ for `tabular*` as that is the only mechanism that environment has to adjust the setting to meet the specified total width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try  this simple code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=3.5cm,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.6pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\textbf{tabularx package}\par\vspace{5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{14mm}{ |X|X| }
    \hline
    \hspace{2pt}foo & \hspace{2pt}bar \\
\hline
\end{tabularx} (1)
\par\vspace{5pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I just tried to use `tabularx` without using the correct environment ^^'. One should mention that you can define the width of single or multiple `X` columns by preceding `>{\hsize=7mm}`. Works!

Comment: One still needs a little calculation, but without exceptions: Using `\begin{tabularx}{14mm}{ |>{\hsize=\dimexpr7mm-2\tabcolsep\relax}X|X| }` does exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: That' not exact. The syntax is `\hsize=coefficient \hize`, to set relative sizes, the condition being that the sum of the coefficients be equal to the number of `X` columns.

Comment: I don't understand how you trick works, but all those calculations are normally done by the package.

Comment: Well, I just calculate the (absolute) correct size for the parbox used. Your `\hsize=..\hsize` is relative of course.

Comment: I don't use `\hsize`. You only have to give tabularx the total width of the table, and it computes the width of `X` columns, it's as simple as that!

Comment: This is not working automatically, if I want to set the sizes manually with absolute values. Same work needs to be done than before, see edited post.

Comment: True. It works automatically with relative sizes only. But do you really need more than that?

Comment: @nox for your first comment, no you can not do that (it will completely break tabularx's calculations)

Answer (score 4):

It's not completely clear what the requirements are but as far as I can see you want a table with two equal columns, three vertical rules and a total width of 14mm, for that I would do the following.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{array}
\newlength\zz

\begin{document}

\setlength\zz{\dimexpr 14mm - 4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\fontsize{3.5pt}{4pt}\selectfont


\begin{tabular}{|p{.5\zz}|p{.5\zz}|}
foo  &bar\\
zz&zzz
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's working, indeed. It looks better as there is not that much fine-tuning needed as in my example. Initially I was looking for a more general approach. One that automatically adjusts to the amount vlines with my choice of lengths for the parboxes. I see now, why `tabularx` is using relative measurement, too.

Comment: There are no real requirements, I am just trying to get used to (la)tex with it's details.

Comment: @nox that's what the code above does you just need to subtract the widths of the vertical lines and 2\tabcolsep table padding for each column, and then distribute the remaining space to your columns. Of course in 99 cases out of 100 the table is better set without verical lines (see the booktabs package documentation for a treatise on the evils of vertical lines in tables:-)

Answer (score 3):

You could define a phantom vrule that takes the same space as a standard rule. Or the other way round a vrule that doesn't take space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{4pt} %for better view

\newcolumntype\pvline{!{\hspace{\arrayrulewidth}}}

\newcolumntype\vline{!{\hspace{-0.5\arrayrulewidth}\vrule width \arrayrulewidth\hspace{-0.5\arrayrulewidth}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{\dimexpr1cm-2\tabcolsep}|p{\dimexpr1cm-2\tabcolsep}}
\hline
blb& blb \\
blb&blbl 
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{p{\dimexpr1cm-2\tabcolsep}\pvline p{\dimexpr1cm-2\tabcolsep}}
\hline
blb& blb
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{p{\dimexpr1cm-2\tabcolsep}\vline p{\dimexpr1cm-2\tabcolsep}}
\hline
blb& blb\\
blb&blbl
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{p{\dimexpr1cm-2\tabcolsep} p{\dimexpr1cm-2\tabcolsep}}
\hline
blb& blb
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works as intended, but still the placement of the outer vlines has not been corrected then.

Comment: If you mean in the second case: that's one of the reasons why array takes the width of the lines into account, so I would prefer the first solution. Regarding tabularx: be aware that it can be difficult to handle if \multicolumn is involved.