# table and column width in a tabular* environment

Tags: tables

As far as I understand, when calculating the width of columns vs the total width of a table, one needs to take into account the right number of `\tabcolsep` and `\arrayrulewidth`.

Suppose that I want to have a table spanning the entire width of the page which contains two equal columns without any vertical lines and where I have removed the empty space on the left and right with the command `@{}` and the left column is left aligned while the right column is right aligned. In that case the code would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, calc, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}p{0.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep}@{}} 
\toprule
text 1 & text 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
   
\end{document}
```

The output is exactly as desired:

[image]

If I would like to decrease the width of the entire table and each column by, let's say 30%, then I implement the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, calc, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\def\tablewidthvalue{0.7}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\tablewidthvalue\linewidth}{@{}p{\tablewidthvalue\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep\relax}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\tablewidthvalue\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep\relax}@{}} 
\toprule
text 1 & text 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
   
\end{document}
```

Essentially I am introducing the scaling factor `\def\tablewidthvalue{0.7}` to both the width of the table and each column. I was expecting that this would work, however it seems that it does not:

[image]

As you can see, `text 2` is sticking beyond the width of the table.

It is worth noting that if I set `\def\tablewidthvalue{1}`, then the alignment works just fine once again.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue? Why scaling the width of each individual column and summing the widths of the scaled columns does not equal scaling the width of the entire table?

PS. I know I could use the `tabularx` package in this case, however I would like to know why the above code does not work properly.

**EDIT:**

I found a way to achieve the result that I want - I simply enclose the `tabular*` environment in a `minipage` and I scale the `\linewidth` of the minipage. I am posting the code below for completeness. However, I would still like to know the answer to the question above.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, calc, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\def\tablewidthvalue{0.7}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{\tablewidthvalue\linewidth}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}p{0.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep}@{}} 
\toprule
text 1 & text 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
   
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Following the suggestion by David below, the following code works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, calc, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\def\tablewidthvalue{0.7}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\tablewidthvalue\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep\relax}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\tablewidthvalue\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep\relax}@{}} 
\toprule
text 1 & text 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it the same thing as defined in the answer below or is there a difference -- adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439683/197451

Comment: You are misusing `tabular*` here, specifying a target width but giving tex no flexible glue to achieve that, use `tabular` not `tabular*`

Comment: @davidcarlisle Thank you, I had indeed misunderstood the difference between `tabular` and `tabular*`. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved very easily with `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec={XX[r]}, colsep=0pt, width=.7\linewidth} 
\toprule
text 1 & text 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

Some text only to show the table is 70\% of line width.
Of course, you can also set any other width using the \texttt{width=} option of \texttt{tabularray} package.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newlength\zz

\begin{document}
    
    \setlength\zz{\dimexpr \textwidth - 4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
    \fontsize{3.5pt}{4pt}\selectfont
    
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.7\zz}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.7\zz}@{}}
        \toprule
        foo  &bar\\
        zz&zzz\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ js Sorry, I am not sure that I understand your answer. In the code you have written , the width of the table is still `\textwidth`, which is not what I want. I want to scale the width of the entire table by scaling the width of each individual column.